# Include automation schedule definition in customization project

Tags: automation, customization, acumatica

I have a processing screen that will be typically scheduled.  I want to include an inactive schedule definition in the customization project to make it easier for the customer.  I cannot locate the option in the customization screen to add an automation.  Is there any way?

Comment: If there is no option you could use a Customization plugin and create the record using the schedule graph after the package is published.

Comment: I had heard data can be added via script in a customization project.  Do you know how to do this?  Can you describe what you mean by a customization plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no option out of the box for including specific entities into a customization project, you can create a Customization plugin which will execute during the end of the publish process. The plugin can be used to work with DACs and Graph to insert, update, delete data as needed. This is preferred to using SQL scripts as its DBMS neutral (works with SQL Server or MySQL).

Here is a help article to add a plugin to a customization project:
[To Add a Customization Plug-In to a Project](https://help.acumatica.com/(W(2))/Wiki/ShowWiki.aspx?pageid=c69443fe-4d32-47a9-85aa-b2882aa259ef)

For your specific question to add an automation schedule you can use the graph related to that page which is `AUScheduleMaint`. Below is a working sample to add the *Release IN Documents (IN501000)* as an inactive schedule if a schedule doesn't already exist as an example. Replace the screen ID and description to fit your needs. If you need a different schedule setup from the default modify the insert of `AUSchedule` as needed.

```
public class MyCustomPlugin : CustomizationPlugin
{

    //This method executed after customization was published and website was restarted.  
    public override void UpdateDatabase()
    {
        CreateSchedule("IN501000", "My New IN501000 Schedule");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create a schedule for a given screen if the screen doesn't have a schedule
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="screenID">Sitemap screen ID</param>
    /// <param name="scheduleDesc">Schedule description when creating a new schedule</param>
    protected virtual void CreateSchedule(string screenID, string scheduleDesc)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(screenID))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("screenID");
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(scheduleDesc))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("scheduleDesc");
        }

        var auScheduleGraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<PX.SM.AUScheduleMaint>();

        var schedule = FindScheduleByScreen(auScheduleGraph, screenID);

        if (schedule != null)
        {
            //schedule exists, no need to create...
            return;
        }

        auScheduleGraph.Schedule.Insert(new PX.SM.AUSchedule
        {
            ScreenID = screenID,
            Description = scheduleDesc,
            IsActive = false,
            StartTime = PX.Common.PXTimeZoneInfo.UtcNow
        });

        auScheduleGraph.Actions.PressSave();

        this.WriteLog(string.Format("Created automation schedule '{0}' for screen '{1}'", scheduleDesc, screenID));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Find an automation schedule by screen ID
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="graph"></param>
    /// <param name="screenID"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected virtual PX.SM.AUSchedule FindScheduleByScreen(PXGraph graph, string screenID)
    {
        PX.SM.AUSchedule auSchedule = null;

        foreach (PX.SM.AUSchedule result in PXSelect<PX.SM.AUSchedule, Where<PX.SM.AUSchedule.screenID, Equal<Required<PX.SM.AUSchedule.screenID>>>>.Select(graph, screenID))
        {
            if (auSchedule == null)
            {
                auSchedule = result;
                continue;
            }

            if (result.IsActive.GetValueOrDefault() && !auSchedule.IsActive.GetValueOrDefault())
            {
                //Find an active if possible
                auSchedule = result;
            }
        }

        return auSchedule;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is awesome.  Thanks for the detail.  One little question, I cannot seem to set the interval to 15 minutes.  Everything I can find tells me it is just a short integer, but when I set Interval = 15 I get an error when trying to add the row.  I even tried (Int16?) and (short?) with no luck.  I also tried to find the graph and DAC in CodeRepository but they don't seem to be visible.

Comment: I think to set the interval you also have to set the endtime field. Are you setting the end time field?

Comment: You are correct!  I tried to enter it on the form and the error showed I needed an end time.  Thanks again.

Comment: no problem. I always walk through my entry in the UI to best determine the field values i need to set. Glad this helped.